# Finding out the frequency of a sine wave

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, signal-processing

I have a signal $x[n]$ which has $500$ samples, and I want to generate it such as it consists of two sinusoids added together.

- The first sinusoid will have an amplitude of $1$, and make $6$
  complete cycles in the $500$ samples.
- The second sinusoid will have an amplitude of $0.5$ and make $44$ complete cycles in the $500$ samples.

Make of plot of this signal.

What I'm not really familiar with is the $6$ complete cycles in $500$ samples part. I assume I should be  using $\sin(2\pi f)$? So I should have something like this $$x[n]= \sin(2\pi f) + 0.5 \sin(2\pi f)$$ I know that the periodic time is the time taken to make one complete cycle, so is the $500$ samples considered as the time unit here?

Answer (score 0):

for first signal:
Ts = 500/6=250/3
f=1/T=3/250
now first sin wave=sin((6/250)*πn)
you can do same operation for second sin signal
so final anwser is
x[n]=sin((6/250)*πn)+0.5sin((88/500)*πn)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).